# How to properly require images in ES6, React Native, CommonJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, commonjs

There are a few images used everywhere in my app. Imagine a user's default avatar, like button icon, etc.

I read the React Docs but they don't go into detail about a better approach to `require` ing images which are used a lot.

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images

My app is structured like this

```
...
./assets/images/like.png
./assets/images/default-avatar.png
./components/Newsfeed.js
./components/Home.js
...
```

I use to `require` in the body of the `render()` function like so. But I noticed the images took quite a while to load.

```
render() {
  ...
  posts && posts.map(post => <Post likeUrl={require('../assets/images/like.png')}>)
  ...
}
```

I was experimenting so I moved the `require` to the top and then refactored in my `Newsfeed.js` and `Home.js`. There was indeed a noticeable improvement when these components loaded.

```
...

const LIKE = require('../assets/images/like.png')

export class Newsfeed extends Component {
  render() {
    ...
    posts && posts.map(post => <Post likeUrl={LIKE}>)
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to know if there's a way to structure the project so that I don't have to `require` in multiple places.

Bonus Points:

1. Would `require`ing once be more performant like I suspect? Or am I just imagining it.
2. If so, what would be a good approach to importing these images into a centralized place, making them exportable, and then importing them into another file for consumption?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: generally speaking, I create a component where I import image and I import that component where I want so you would only have to import once in your component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I want to use an image multiple times in my application, then I will do something like this.

1. I create a common file called 'image_container.js' and make changes like below:

```js
export const Likes = require('./assets/images/like.png')
export const DefaultAvatar = require('./assets/images/default-avatar.png')
```

2. I will import the images from that file to use it.

```js
import { Likes, DefaultAvatar } from './image_container'

export class Newsfeed extends Component {
  render() {
      ...
      posts && posts.map(post => <Post likeUrl={Likes}>)
      ...
  }
}
```

By doing like this, I am requiring the images once and using it multiple times in my application.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Since @Thinker solution seems to be working for you I just add another solution. I suggest you reduce your project image assets to almost 0. There is always trouble with importing images. Not only they will aggressively increase your git repo size but also they are very hard to manage in CSS. You also don't want to require the same file for both mobile and desktop. Also every time you request an image that is hosted at the same domain as your code, You will also have to transfer cookies which is not optimal. So let's wrap up the issues that come with importing images in code:

1. Mobile/Desktop optimization is hard (you need to have 1x, 2x and 3x as well)
2. Same cookies and probably cache settings with your code host
3. Significantly increases your code repo

My suggestion is to use a CDN as soon as you can effort one. Alibaba OSS (china) offers very cheap but yet high quality service. You can use CSS media queries to handle different sizes by setting different background images. Alibaba also gives you this nice feature that you only need to upload your 3x size and get 2x and 1x by passing different query parameters. Cache settings and all CDN concerns are also fixed. If you don't want to buy anything you can also do the same thing your self with less features and more headache but I don't recommend.